# What are the dlls required by gta san andreas, and does wine look in the game directory for dll files?

Tags: linux, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas, wine

I am trying to play gta san andreas on linux with wine. Wine gives the following error when I try to launch the game:

> err:module:load_builtin_dll failed to load .so lib for builtin L"winemp3.acm": libmpg123.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x177f594,0x00000000), stub!
>   fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x177f584,0x00000000), stub!
>   fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x177f334,0x00000000), stub!
>   fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x177f7c4,0x00000000), stub!
>   fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x20.
>   fixme:system:SystemParametersInfoW Unimplemented action: 59 (SPI_SETSTICKYKEYS)
>   fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x20.
>   fixme:d3d:swapchain_gl_present WINED3D_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP not implemented.
>   err:quartz:GetClassMediaFile Media class not found
>   fixme:quartz:FM2_ReadFilterData Filter registry version 536870914 not supported
>   fixme:quartz:MPEGSplitter_QueryInterface No interface for {37d84f60-42cb-11ce-8135-00aa004bb851}!
>   fixme:quartz:MPEGSplitter_query_accept MPEG-1 system streams not yet supported.
>   wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x00000000 at address 0x74812b (thread 0009), starting debugger...
>   err:dbghelp_msc:codeview_process_info Unknown CODEVIEW signature 8c2e96f8 in module L"gta_sa"

It complains something about dll in the first line. I installed the game on windows about a year ago and it didn't run out of the box. I had to place some dll files, I do not remember which ones, in the game directory to make it work. What are the extra dlls required by gta san andreas? And will it work if I just place those dlls in the game folders,  as it does in windows, or do I need to install them using winetricks?

Edit:

The game runs after installing d3dx9, but the frame rate is very low, same as windows. This problem required directx11 and video drivers to get fixed on windows. I already had directx11 installed on wine though. Any ideas about it?

Comment: Actually, the error isn't about missing DLLs, it's about a `.so lib` which apparently failed to load. I don't use Linux much these days, and I haven't used Wine in decades, so that's as far as I can help.

Comment: Thanks, I installed d3dx9 and the game runs now, but it's very choppy, just as it was on windows at first. I had to install directx11 and video driver for my pc to fix it. I'll edit the question to include that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend dual-booting a windows 7 lite version, I've been playing many games on Wine and on PlayOnLinux and it will never be as stable as on it's native OS. I dedicated one of my SSD for my Windows and the rest of my drives for my linux (work/school/etc).
If you want to play GTA San Andreas stable on linux you'll need to buy a very expensive Graphic Card which is not worth it for these type of games.

With that said, if you still want to try to stabilize your gaming experience, here's what I recommend, download the latest stable Nvidia drivers with these commands:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nvidia-364 (check whatever version we're at at this day on google)

**Source:**
I've been trying to play on linux for years and I'm sad

Comment: I have a laptop,  so a new graphics card is out of options.  I'll give a try to nvidia drivers, although my lappy has intel chipset.  ps: I share your pain.  In six months, the only free fps game worth playing I found is doom 3.  Maybe that's why our teacher recommended us to use linux ;-D

Comment: @Saga I can't work on Windows it's pretty annoying for real. If you have intel graphic card, the only solution is dual boot. And you should save to build a Desktop for gaming/programming, I don't really like laptops tbh! Good luck